# Can I control the formatting of multiline strings?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

The following code:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys, textwrap

yaml = YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.dump({
    'hello.py': textwrap.dedent("""\
        import sys
        sys.stdout.write("hello world")
    """)
}, sys.stdout)
```

produces:

```
hello.py: "import sys\nsys.stdout.write(\"hello world\")\n"
```

is there a way to make it produce:

```
hello.py: |
    import sys
    sys.stdout.write("hello world")
```

instead?

Versions:

```
python: 2.7.16 on Win10 (1903)
ruamel.ordereddict==0.4.14
ruamel.yaml==0.16.0
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.1.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you load, then dump, your expected output, you'll see that `ruamel.yaml` can actually 
preserve the block style literal scalar.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
hello.py: |
    import sys
    sys.stdout.write("hello world")
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

as this gives again the loaded input:

```
hello.py: |
  import sys
  sys.stdout.write("hello world")
```

To find out how it does that you should inspect the type of your multi-line string:

```
print(type(data['hello.py']))
```

which prints:

```
<class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString'>
```

and that should point you in the right direction:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import LiteralScalarString
import sys, textwrap

def LS(s):
    return LiteralScalarString(textwrap.dedent(s))


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump({
    'hello.py': LS("""\
        import sys
        sys.stdout.write("hello world")
    """)
}, sys.stdout)
```

which also outputs what you want:

```
hello.py: |
  import sys
  sys.stdout.write("hello world")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! (https://github.com/datakortet/yamldirs/commit/ba7517d0ab9a2c32554079e9c51ec9fe8b0984f4)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to achieve this without needing to prefix all of your multi-line strings with the LS() function? This current solution means that you can't just dump a regular dict to yaml, but instead have the identity each multiline string and add the function before dumping.

Comment: @JoeJ There is a utility function `walk_tree` in `scalarstring.py` that does that for simple data structures recursively. But it is of course also possible to do that during dumping, although with less control.