# How to format a string in YAML dump?

Tags: string, formatting, dump, ruamel.yaml

Dumping **multiline** strings with ruamel.yaml results this:

```
address_pattern_template: "\n^                           #the beginning of the address\
  \ string (e.g. interface number)\n(?P<junkbefore>             #capturing the junk\
  \ before the address\n    \\D?                     #an optional non-digit character\n\
  \    .*?                     #any characters (non-greedy) up to the address\n)\n\
  (?P<address>                #capturing the pure address\n    {pure_address_pattern}\n\
  )\n(?P<junkafter>              #capturing the junk after the address\n    \\D? \
  \                    #an optional non-digit character\n    .*                  \
  \    #any characters (greedy) up to the end of the string\n)\n$                \
  \           #the end of the input address string\n"
```

The code is like this:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
data =dict(
address_pattern_template="""
^                           #the beginning of the address string (e.g. interface number)
(?P<junkbefore>             #capturing the junk before the address
    \D?                     #an optional non-digit character
    .*?                     #any characters (non-greedy) up to the address
)
(?P<address>                #capturing the pure address
    {pure_address_pattern}
)
(?P<junkafter>              #capturing the junk after the address
    \D?                     #an optional non-digit character
    .*                      #any characters (greedy) up to the end of the string
)
$                           #the end of the input address string
"""
)
yaml = YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)
yaml.default_flow_style = False
with open('D:\datadump.yml', 'w') as dumpfile:
    yaml.dump(data, dumpfile)
```

I would like to see the multi-line string in a readable format. I.e. newline characters are to break the lines instead of displayed as '\n'.

What flags/options can I set so that it appears like this:

```
address_pattern_template: |
  ^                           #the beginning of the address string (e.g. interface number)
  (?P<junkbefore>             #capturing the junk before the address
      \D?                     #an optional non-digit character
      .*?                     #any characters (non-greedy) up to the address
  )
  (?P<address>                #capturing the pure address
      {pure_address_pattern}
  )
  (?P<junkafter>              #capturing the junk after the address
      \D?                     #an optional non-digit character
      .*                      #any characters (greedy) up to the end of the string
  )
  $                           #the end of the input address string
```

NB, my program logs a big dict, and such multi-line strings can occur anywhere and any deep in the dict structure. So, walking through the dict tree and load each of them prior to the dump (as proposed in "Can I control the formatting of multiline strings?") is not a good solution for me.

I wonder whether the dumper could be directed with a parameter to recognise multi-line strings and dump them in block format. Single-line strings can still be in the same line as the colon. This makes the log file the most readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I control the formatting of multiline strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382525/can-i-control-the-formatting-of-multiline-strings)

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution does not apply to this problem, so I added a paragraph to the request explaining it a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what you present as that what you would like to get as output,
is not a representation of the data that you provide. Since
the multi-line string in that data starts with a newline, the block
style literal scalar for that requires a block indentation indicator and a newline at the start:

```
address_pattern_template: |2

  ^                           #the beginning of the address string (e.g. interface number)
  .
  .
  .
```

But it doesn't make sense (to me at least) to have these patterns
start with a newline, so I'll leave that out in the following.

---

If you don't know where the multi-line strings are in your data structure, but if you can 
convert it in-place before dumping, than you can use `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring:walk_tree`

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = dict(a=[1, 2, 3, dict(
address_pattern_template="""\
^                           #the beginning of the address string (e.g. interface number)
(?P<junkbefore>             #capturing the junk before the address
    \D?                     #an optional non-digit character
    .*?                     #any characters (non-greedy) up to the address
)
(?P<address>                #capturing the pure address
    {pure_address_pattern}
)
(?P<junkafter>              #capturing the junk after the address
    \D?                     #an optional non-digit character
    .*                      #any characters (greedy) up to the end of the string
)
$                           #the end of the input address string
"""
)])


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.walk_tree(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a:
- 1
- 2
- 3
- address_pattern_template: |
    ^                           #the beginning of the address string (e.g. interface number)
    (?P<junkbefore>             #capturing the junk before the address
        \D?                     #an optional non-digit character
        .*?                     #any characters (non-greedy) up to the address
    )
    (?P<address>                #capturing the pure address
        {pure_address_pattern}
    )
    (?P<junkafter>              #capturing the junk after the address
        \D?                     #an optional non-digit character
        .*                      #any characters (greedy) up to the end of the string
    )
    $                           #the end of the input address string
```

`walk_tree` will replace the the multiline string with
`LiteralScalarString`, which behave for most purposes like a normal
string.

If that in-place transform is not acceptable, you can do a deepcopy of
data first and then apply `walk_tree` on the copy. If that is not is acceptable 
because of memory constraints, then you have to provide an alternative representer for strings
that checks during representation if you have multi-line string. Preferably you do that
in a subclass the Representer:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

# data defined as before

class MyRepresenter(ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter):
    def represent_str(self, data):
        style = '|' if '\n' in data else None
        return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style=style)


MyRepresenter.add_representer(str, MyRepresenter.represent_str)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Representer = MyRepresenter
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives the same output as the previous example.

Comment: I knew the potential was in ruamel.yaml, I just could not figure such solution out from the documentation (I did not see there anything like this).

Comment: Correct, the newline is not at the beginning, I just created the wrong example. I used your trick. It works like a charm until I add the "typ='safe'" to the constructor, because with "safe" it gives me "RepresenterError: cannot represent an object". Does it consider the multi-line string a complex object (which is not safe) rather than a plain string?

Comment: I presented two "tricks" and I am not sure which one you used. If you instantiate with `typ='safe'` you are going to use the `SafeRepresenter` and not the `RoundTripRepresenter`, and then you have to make adjustments. When you use `walk_tree`, you'll get objects that the `SafeRepresenter` does not know about. Since you are using `pure=True` and the RoundTripRepresenter being as safe as the SafeRepresenter, I don't see the need to use `typ="safe"`.

Comment: And as for documentation, I should maybe just start with scraping all my answers here on SO and publish them as one document ;-)

Comment: I use your 1st solution proposal. Exactly, 'safe' does not make much sense in my case, so I just removed it. A more detailed documentation would be much appreciated by the growing number of ruamel.yaml users. I now use YAML for both configs and logs. As I am a beginner here, I am not allowed to vote it up, but already accepted the answer. Thanks again.